# FillGeometry much slower on UWP compared to desktop?

Tags: performance, desktop, uwp, direct2d, sharpdx

The UWP version of our app runs with a much slower framerate (6 fps vs 24 fps) compared to the desktop equivalent. Note that both versions were tested on the *same* hardware.

Both versions are built using SharpDX, the only difference is how the RenderTargets are set up. The Windows app uses an `HwndRenderTarget`, and the UWP app uses a `SurfaceImageSource` brush that paints into a `Rectangle`.

We've narrowed the main culprit (on the CPU side at least) to `FillGeometry`, which consumes a lot of the time on UWP.

Is there a reason why `FillGeometry` would take much longer in the above UWP configuration compared to desktop?

Note: The rendering code is identical on both, so avoid suggestions which impact both implementations equally, such as using `GeometryRealization` instead of `Geometry`. We're looking for the reason for the difference between the rendering performance on UWP and desktop.

If there are factors other than Geometry that might be affecting performance, it would be useful to know those as well, since our profiling tools might not be altogether precise.

Comment: I am sure the desktop computer has much better graphics card than the phone.  Better graphics card means better gpu

Comment: Does this performance issue happen with and without .NET Native (DEBUG/RELEASE builds in VS)? They have different interop and compiler stacks so that may help in tracking this down.

Comment: Ken - both versions were run on the same machine. Matt - both are DEBUG builds. .Net native has issues (it never completes) so can't use that at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the factors seems to be that internal Direct2D clipping works differently in these cases.

Our scene has hundreds of geometries, and our initial code did not clip to the viewport, and relied instead on Direct2D doing the clipping. This resulted in the differences in frame rates mentioned in the original post.

When explicit clipping was added, the frame rate for the UWP version increased to around 16fps (still less than that of the desktop app) while the frame rate of the desktop version was not affected much.

So at this point it is a hypothesis that different clipping routines are at work in these two cases.

This isn't fully solved, as we still have a significant difference in frame rates. But it's a start.